# Using these atomic operations with memory order relaxed and rel/acq as shown, does this C++ snippet work?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, memory-model, compare-and-swap

Written in cppmem pseudo code:

```
int main()                                                                                                                                                                                   
{                                                                                                                                                                                            
  atomic_int n = -1;                                                                                                                                                                         
  atomic_int n2 = 0;                                                                                                                                                                         

  {{{                                                                                                                                                                                        
      {                                                                                                                                                                                      
        n2.store(1, mo_relaxed);                                                                                                                                                             
        if (n.load(mo_relaxed) != -1)                                                                                                                                                        
          n.store(1, mo_release);                                                                                                                                                            
      }                                                                                                                                                                                      
  |||                                                                                                                                                                                        
      {                                                                                                                                                                                      
        n.store(0, mo_release);                                                                                                                                                              
        int expected = 0;                                                                                                                                                                    
        do                                                                                                                                                                                   
        {                                                                                                                                                                                    
          desired = n2.load(mo_relaxed);                                                                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                                                                                                    
        while (!n.compare_exchange_strong(&expected, desired, mo_acquire));                                                                                                                  
      }                                                                                                                                                                                      
  }}}                                                                                                                                                                                        

  assert(n == 1);                                                                                                                                                                            
}
```

In words, two atomic variables are initialized as n = -1 and n2 = 0;

Thread 1 first writes 1 to n2 and then to n, provided n wasn't (still) -1.

Thread 2 first writes 0 to n, then loads n2 and assigns n = n2 as long as n wasn't changed since it last read n (or when n is still 0).

After both threads joined n must equal 1 in every possible execution.

This code is part of an open source project of me and related to resetting a streambuf implementation to the start of the buffer lock-free while two threads concurrently read and write to it. This particular part has to do with 'sync-ing' (or, flushing written output).

I designed this and it works when every operation is sequentially consistent (this was brute force tested), but I can't wrap my head around the memory order requirements :/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assertion could fire if instructions (and cache updates) are performed in this order:

- The first threads run all its instructions. So it just change the value of `n2` from `0` to `1`.
- Then threads 2 runs. First it changes the value of `n` from `-1` to `0`.
- Then threads 2 loads `n2` (in `n2.load(mo_relaxed)`). At this point there are no synchronizations so any value previously stored in `n2` (including the initialization value, see [[intro.race]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.exec#intro.races-1)) can be loaded. Let's say it loads `0`.
- So threads 2 variable values are `n==0` (the last one in the modification order of `n`),`n2==0`, `expected==0`, `desired==0` before the compare exchange instruction. Then, the compare exchange succeeds, and stores `0` in `n`.

At the end of the execution of the two threads you get `n==0` and `n2==1`.

With sequential consistency what I described cannot happen because if thread 1 saw `n2==1 && n==-1`, thread 2 could not see `n2==0 && n==0`.

With this algorithm I am sure it is not possible to use any other memory order than sequential consistency.

Comment: Thank you very much for your analysis. I was already afraid that the current code was too relaxed-- but are you sure that it can only work with sequential consistency? I'd like to avoid any seq-cst if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using a tool that I found on https://plv.mpi-sws.org/rcmc/
I was able to experimentally find that the most relaxed requirements are:

Thread1:

```
n2.store(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
if (n.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst) != -1)
  n.store(1, std::memory_order_release);
```

Thread2:

```
n.store(0, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
int expected = 0;
int desired;
do
{
    desired = n2.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
}
while (!n.compare_exchange_strong(expected, desired,
    std::memory_order_acquire, std::memory_order_relaxed));
```

EDIT:

A more recent tool by the same authors (which is also better, of course)
can now be downloaded from https://github.com/MPI-SWS/genmc

This tool turns out to be extremely fast and useful, even for testing Real-Life algorithms that use weakly ordered atomics, as for example I am doing here: [genmc_buffer_reset_test.c](https://github.com/CarloWood/ai-evio-testsuite/blob/master/src/genmc_buffer_reset_test.c#L101)

The #include's at the given line are generated C files, extracted from my C++ code and transformed to C with awk scripts, because it seems to me that genmc can (unfortunately) only be used for C code(?).